# addClass to a div and then apply on click to that new class, Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, click, addclass, toggleclass

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8TxmK/

I have two divs, one which has class="bb" and another with no classes. In my jquery, I apply the following functions:

```
$('div').on('click',(function(){

    $(this).addClass('bb');

}));

$('.bb').on('click',(function(){

    alert('bb class clicked')

}));
```

So I want to addClass 'bb' to the second div when clicked. This works fine. However, the second part 'bb' on click doesn't work for the div which 'bb' class wasn't loaded from the beginning.

Is there any workaround for this?

I have tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/M8Ja4/
But the function repeats itself once more each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.. delegate.  Replace body with the closest parent that exists when the dom is loaded

```
$('body').on('click','.bb',function(){

});
```

Comment: One more question, how would I select that '.bb' inside that function? If I use $(this) it selects body.

Comment: It should select the `.bb` that triggered the event and not the `body` or parent http://jsfiddle.net/8TxmK/7/

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.  If you are on jQuery 1.7+, use the `.on()` method to attach the event handler dynamically:

```
$(document).on('click','.bb',function() { });
```

If you are using an older version of jQuery, use `.delegate()`:

```
$(document).delegate('.bb','click',function() { });
```

Although these examples use `document`, you can use any DOM element.  My suggestions is to use the lowest one possible (closest ancestor to the elements to `.bb`), as that way you can capture the event sooner and, if necessary, prevent propagation all the way to the document level.  You may hear of the `.live()` method, but that has been deprecated in 1.7 and the jQuery team recommends discontinuing usage even on older projects.

Your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8TxmK/4/) posted in the comments of another answer is a perfect example of event bubbling.

```
<style>
    div{width:300px;height:100px;background:pink;margin-bottom:10px;}
    .bb{border:10px solid black;}
​</style>

<div></div>
<div class="bb"></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () }{

        $('div').on('click',(function(){
            $(this).addClass('bb');
        }));

        $('body').on('click','.bb',function(){
            alert('bb class clicked');
        });
    ​});
</script>
```

In that example, when you click on the `div` without the `bb` class, it gets the class added, then the event bubbles up to the `body` and triggers there, which is why the alert pops up on the *first* click.

Comment: +1 for explaining event bubbling & mentioning deprecation of live, cheers!